# How to insert "\n" in the second space in one string?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, replace

I want to insert `\n` in the second space in a string, so for example if a string has more than 1 space, it means I can add `\n` in the second space, if not, it means it is just one word or a string with  one space and I would like to have and `else` where I can print it normal, so in this example, I have `Hi I am here testing` string, then I would like to raplace the second space with `\n` then it would be `Hi I\nam here testing` so in console it would print that string in the next way:

```
Hi I
am here testing
```

I was trying to do this with `replace(/ /g,"\n")` but it replaces all spaces.
I hope someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: what if you have a space at the third position not at the second position

Comment: @gsharew I think OP means the second space, not necessarily at the second index/index 2 (which are different anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a regex to match from start of string up to the second group of spaces (1 or more) and replace that set of spaces with a newline:

```js
const str = 'Hi I am here testing'

const regex = /^(\S+\s+\S+)\s+/

const result = str.replace(regex, '$1\n')
console.log(result)
```

Another possibility is to split the string on spaces and then join it back together with a newline replacing the space between the second and third word:

```js
const str = 'Hi I am here testing'

const parts = str.split(/(\s+)/)

const result = parts.slice(0, 3).join('') + '\n' + parts.slice(4).join('')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with foreach in an easy way

```js
    var myname = "alex is software engineer";
    myname = myname.split("");
    var actualString = "";
    var spaceCounter = 0;
    myname.forEach(element => {
        if(element != " ")
        {
            actualString += element;
        }
        else 
        {
            spaceCounter++;
            if(spaceCounter == 2)
            {
                actualString +="\n";
                return;
            }
            else 
            {
                actualString += " ";
            }
        }
    });
     console.log(actualString);
```

Comment: The above solution already fails for `"alex  is software engineer"` (2 spaces in between `alex` and `is`) due to the approach not taking whitespace sequences in between words into account.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
function breakLineOnSecondSpace(sentence) {
  const SPACE = ' ';
  var spaceCount = 0;
  var secondSpaceIndex = -1;

  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    var char = sentence[i];
    if (char == SPACE) spaceCount++;

    if (spaceCount === 2) {
      secondSpaceIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (secondSpaceIndex > -1) {
    return [
      sentence.substring(0, secondSpaceIndex),
      sentence.substring(secondSpaceIndex + 1, sentence.length),
    ].join('\n');
  } else {
    return sentence;
  }
}

console.log(breakLineOnSecondSpace('Hi I am here testing'));
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8y46ku?file=index.js)

Comment: Did you know that you can include a Stack Snippet inside your post? There is no need to link to an external service for this.

Comment: The above solution already fails for `'Hi  I am here testing'` (2 spaces in between `Hi` and `I`) due to the approach not taking whitespace sequences in between words into account.

Answer (score 0):

And here is another possibility with `.replace()` involving a callback function:

```js
const str = 'Hi    I am here testing'
let i=0;res=str.replace(/\s+/g,m=>1==i++?"\n":m);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This one is robust. But the approach is a bazooka since replace will be invoked not only for the 1st and 2nd matching whitespace sequence but for all other `10_000_...` following ones as well.